# Getting error when executing the Java project with Quarkus Maven plugin (Java jdk-17.jd version and Maven 3.9.0

Tags: quarkus

I' m getting the below error when I execute a project in using Quarkus maven plugin. The script executed by me was

```bash
mvn -U io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:create \
    -DprojectGroupId=org.test.quarkus.microservices \
    -DprojectArtifactId=rest-number \
    -DclassName="org.test.quarkus.microservices.number.NumberResource" \
    -Dpath="/api/numbers" \
    -Dextensions="resteasy-jsonb, smallrye-openapi"
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.0.Alpha4:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.0.Alpha4:create failed: A required class was missing while executing io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.0.Alpha4:create: org/eclipse/aether/connector/basic/BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory

Comment: Not an answer, but it appears that Quarkus is not the only affected project: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Issues-with-Maven-3-9-0-when-deploying

Comment: I do not know whether this Maven bug has anything to do with the observed phenomenon: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7471

Answer (score 2):

#### The problem

Maven 3.9.0 using
`org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-connector-basic:1.9.4` as a transitive library.

The `create` goal probably referenced to
`org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory`. Howerver that class exists, running the goal throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

After some investigation it seems only `create` goal affected.

#### Workaround

Downgrade Maven version if it is possible.

Maven release archive is available here: https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/

I've tested with **3.8.7** and **3.8.4**, and both of them work properly.

#### Alternate solution

Alternatively Quarkus has a command line interface. https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling

I didn't tested.

#### Bulletproof solution

An awesome interactive configurator page available here: https://code.quarkus.io/

As I mentioned the generated project will work with Maven 3.9.0

### Update on Apr, 2023

The reported [issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/31011) have already been resolved and released in Quarkus 3.x stream (especially Quarkus 3.0.0.CR1) Unfortunately there's no commitment to backport this bugfix into Quarkus 2.x.

Comment: Thanks @zforgo , when I downgraded the maven version the issue was resolved.